# How to show sftp progress

Tags: bash, sftp, zenity

I have script that sftp files . i would like to display a progress bar showing the transfer  of the files

```
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@ftpsite.com << !
 cd offload
 put /media/*/*.tgz |zenity --progress --auto-close
 bye
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@ftpsite.com << !
 progress
 cd offload
 put /media/*/*.tgz |zenity --progress --auto-close
 bye
```

From `man sftp`:

> ```
>  progress
>    Toggle display of progress meter.
> ```

Comment: i need a pop window to display , not the the progress to display in the bash window

Comment: There is nothing like popup in `sftp` command-line tool. If you need popup, use Filezilla or some other GUI applications.